# TypeError: initialize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Tags: python, tags, tornado

I don't know what this error is: **in __init__
self.initialize(**kwargs)  # type: ignore
TypeError: initialize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'**

I am using python as a backend. I a new here. In this code, I am using tornado web. Yes this code is debugging but as I open `localhost:8882/` & `localhost:8882/animals` on my browser it shows this error. Please help me

my index.py page code:-

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop


class basicRequestHandler(tornado.web.RedirectHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('Hello, World this is python Command from backend')


class listRequestHandler(tornado.web.RedirectHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.request.render('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/",basicRequestHandler),
        (r"/animals", listRequestHandler),
    ])
        
    port = 8882
    app.listen(port)
    print(f"Application is ready and listening on port {port}")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

and my index.html page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>List of Animals</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the list of Animals</h1>
    <select>
        <option>Cat</option>
        <option>Horse</option>
        <option>Rat</option>
        <option>Cow</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the full error with trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using `tornado.web.RequestHandler` instead of `tornado.web.RedirectHandler`.
Edit this in `basicRequestHandler` and `listRequestHandler`, so it matches the following:

```
class basicRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('Hello, World this is python Command from backend')


class listRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.request.render('index.html')
```

Then you'll get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPServerRequest' object has no attribute 'render'
```

This is because you do `self.request.render('index.html')`, which needs to be `self.render('index.html')`, so your final code looks like this:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop


class basicRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('Hello, World this is python Command from backend')


class listRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/",basicRequestHandler),
        (r"/animals", listRequestHandler),
    ])

    port = 8882
    app.listen(port)
    print(f"Application is ready and listening on port {port}")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```